# Old ubuntu breezy apt/dpkg broken

Tags: upgrade

We have an old ubuntu breezy server which someone unsucessfully has tried to upgrade in the past. We need it upgraded, but almost all apt-get operations return something like this:

```
apt-get install -f

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 49 not upgraded.
3 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0B of archives.
After unpacking 0B of additional disk space will be used.
Can't exec "locale": No such file or directory at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/Encoding.pm line 16.
Use of uninitialized value in scalar chomp at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/Encoding.pm line >17.
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of apt:
dpkg (1.14.5ubuntu16) breaks apt (<< 0.7.6ubuntu6) and is installed.
Version of apt to be configured is 0.6.43.3ubuntu2.
dpkg: error processing apt (--configure):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of apt-utils:
apt-utils depends on libapt-pkg-libc6.3-6-3.11; however:
Package libapt-pkg-libc6.3-6-3.11 is not installed.
Package apt which provides libapt-pkg-libc6.3-6-3.11 is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing apt-utils (--configure):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of aptitude:
aptitude depends on libapt-pkg-libc6.3-6-3.11; however:
Package libapt-pkg-libc6.3-6-3.11 is not installed.
Package apt which provides libapt-pkg-libc6.3-6-3.11 is not configured yet.
dpkg (1.14.5ubuntu16) breaks aptitude (<< 0.4.6.1-1ubuntu2) and is installed.
Version of aptitude to be configured is 0.4.0-5ubuntu3.
dpkg: error processing aptitude (--configure):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
apt
apt-utils
aptitude
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Any ideas as to how i can correct this, so we can upgrade one ver. at a time (or up to 10.04)

Comment: Ok, apparently lsb_release -a gives me this: -so it's more "out of shape" than i thought. Some of it runs as breezy... 
    LSB Version:    n/a
    Distributor ID: Ubuntu
    Description:    Ubuntu 6.06 LTS
    Release:        6.06
    Codename:       dapper

Comment: have you tried doing "sudo dpkg --configure -a "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has `dpkg` 1.14.5ubuntu16 from Gutsy installed and tries to update `apt` to 0.6.43.3ubuntu2 from Dapper, but this `apt` version  is incompatible with the installed `dpkg` (and quite likely so is the currently installed version of apt).

If you really want to upgrade change your sources.list to use gutsy (http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ has it). Then manually download and install `apt` from Gutsy (and anything it needs) and try to `dist-upgrade`.

But I would think about a fresh install as a mix of Dapper and Gutsy sounds quite ugly and if there are still some packages from Breezy left that doesn't make it any better.

Comment: Thanks, u r right, but this particular server must be upgraded before a new replacement can be set up in addition to this (don't ask - it's a 'very' custom system) Anyway, that seems to have done the trick.